# How to prove that interval $(x-1,x]$ contains exactly one integer?

Tags: real-analysis, integers

The exersise says that "Show that for any real number x, the interval $(x-1,x]$ contains exactly one integer", though there's a hint which says that consider three separately cases : $x\in \mathbb{Z}$,$(x \in \mathbb{R\setminus Z})\wedge(x>0)$, $(x \in \mathbb{R\setminus Z})\wedge(x<0)$, I don't know how to write them explicitly.

My attempt are belows:

Step1: try to prove the uniqueness.

If there are two integers $t$,$s$ and $t$ is not equal to $s$. So, |s-t|>=1, but distance between every two real numbers in (x-1,x] should strictly less than 1, it's contradict, so at most one integer in (x-1,x].

Step2: try to prove the existance.

Think about set S={$s \in \mathbb{Z}$|s<=x}, due to archimedian's property, we can conclude that S is not empty.And S has an upper bound x, so due to "maximum exists in subset of $\mathbb{Z}$", S has a maximum $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now I try to prove that l is contained in (x-1,x]. From definition of S, we know that $l$<=$x$.Now we try to prove that $l$>$x-1$. If not, that is $l$<=$x-1$, so $l+1$>=$l$,and $l+1$<=$x$, so $l+1 \in S$, it contradicts that $l$ is the maximum.

Can anyone tell me if my proof is true? Or if there some place where need to improve?

Comment: Just take two distinct integers $a, b$ with $a<b$ in that interval. And then $x-1<a<b\leq x$. Can you derive a contradiction now?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: length of interval is $1$ and not less than $1$.

Comment: Next try to figure out a contradiction if there are no integers in this interval.

Comment: Please try and post your attempt in question based on the hints I provided. Posting questions which are just problem statements are discouraged here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your advice. I have put my attempt on it.

Comment: I think $s$ should be in $\Bbb{Z} $ and $l$ as well.

Comment: @kingW3 Thank you for your advice. That's my fault. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not explicitly write the solution in Logic notation but I have the answer.

**Existence of the integer:** Suppose $x$ is not an integer. Take $[x]$ as the greatest integer function. Clearly $x-1<[x]<x$ so the existence is justified.

**Uniqueness of the integer:** Clearly there is no integer between $x$ and $[x]$ as then it would contradict the definition of greatest integer function and also there can not be any integer between $x-1$ and $[x]$ (why? Because if there is an integer $y$ such that $x-1<y<[x]<x$ then we have $0<[x]-y<x-y<1$, now the difference between two integers can never be non-integer! hence it is a contradiction).

This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For every $y,z \in (x-1,x]$ we have $|y-z|<1$ because size of this interval is $1$ and you can't take elements on it's edge. For every two integers $n,m$ we have $|n-m|\geq 1$ so it would be contradiction if they were both in this interval.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.