# How do I prove this claim? If the distance between two numbers is one there is one integer between them (or equal to one of them).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

Let $x,y\in \mathbb R, s.t: y-x=1.$
Claim: there exists a *single* $n\in \mathbb Z, s.t: x\le n<y.$ It's not an excersise, I only want it to prove a theorem, so I guess it might be easy. However I didn't manage to prove it.

Comment: Hint: consider the greatest integer not greater than $x$. If it equals $x$, you are done.  Otherwise...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4069214/how-to-prove-that-interval-x-1-x-contains-exactly-one-integer